# Email css: Alternative way of position:absolute in Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm trying to make a progress bar like in conditional data bars in excel.

The codes that I've provided works in web, but not in outlook since it doesn't support style: position.... Is there alternative way of doing overlay email html?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#summary {font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width:125%; border-collapse:collapse;text-align: center; p style="font-size:12px"}
#summary td, #summary th, #summary ts {font-size:1em;border:1px solid #217DBF;padding:3px 7px 2px 7px; text-align: center;}
#summary th{font-size:.8em;text-align:left;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:4px;background-color:#217DBF;color:#ffffff;text-align: center;}
#summary ts{font-size:1.1em;text-align:left;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:4px;background-color:#DB1D27;color:#ffffff;text-align: center;}
#summary tr.alt td{color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;text-align: center;}
#summary td.important {color:#000000;background-color:#DB1D27;text-align: center;}
#summary td.late{color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#DB1D27;text-align: center;}
#summary td.early{color:#000000;background-color:#08FE19;text-align: center;}
#summary td.ontime{color:#000000;background-color:#0890FE;text-align: center;}
#summary td.nocall{color:#000000;background-color:#F9B52D;text-align: center;}
#summary tr.alt td.nocall{color:#000000;background-color:#F9B52D;text-align: center;}
#summary tr.alt td.late{color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#DB1D27; text-align: center;}
#summary tr.alt td.early{color:#000000;background-color:#08FE19;text-align: center;}
#summary tr.alt td.ontime{color:#000000;background-color:#0890FE;text-align: center;}
#summary td.standout {color:#000000;background-color:#FAFF52;text-align: center;}
#summary tr.alt td.standout{color:#000000;background-color:#FAFF52;text-align: center;}

.meter {position: relative; z-index: 5;}
.meter span {display:block; height: 100%; background-color: #ffcd30; position: absolute; left: 0px; top:0px; z-index:-1;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="summary" border="1" bordercolor=#AAD2F3>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th> <th>Calls In</th> <th>Dur In</th> <th>Calls Out</th> <th>Dur Out</th> <th>Tot Calls</th> <th>Tot Dur</th>
            <th>Calls + Mins</th> <th>First Call</th> <th>Last Call</th> <th>Ext Email Received</th> <th>Int Email Received</th> <th>Total Email Received</th>
            <th>Ext Email Sent</th> <th>Int Email Sent</th> <th>Total Email Sent</th> <th>CarahDial Calls</th> <th>Carahdial VMs</th> <th>CarahEmployee calls</th>
            <th>Cust Created</th> <th>Cust Mod</th> <th>Quotes Created</th> <th>Quotes Mod</th><th>IM Sent</th><th>IM Rec</th> 
        </tr>

        <tr class="alt">
            <td nowrap>"Date</td><td> 3 </td><td> 12.1</td><td> 3  </td><td>38.88</td>
            <td>  <a>4</a> </td><td>  14.52 </td>
            <td class = "standout meter"><span style="width: 60%;"></span> 30  </td>  <td>4:20p</td>
            <td>77  </td><td>200  </td><td> <a>277 </a> </td><td> 30  </td><td>60  </td><td class = "standout"> 90 </td>
            <td> 0  </td><td>0 </td><td> 0  </td><td>0  </td><td>0  </td><td>0  </td>
            <td> 0  </td><td>0  </td><td>0 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style = "background-color:#D3ECF2;">
            <td nowrap>" "Date)"</td><td> 3 </td><td> 12.1</td><td> 3  </td><td>38.88</td>
            <td>  <a>4</a> </td><td>  14.52 </td>
            <td class = "standout meter"> <span style=" width: 100%;"></span> 100 </td>  <td>4:20p</td>
            <td>77  </td><td>200  </td><td> <a>277 </a> </td><td> 30  </td><td>60  </td><td class = "standout"> 90 </td>
            <td> 0  </td><td>0 </td><td> 0  </td><td>0  </td><td>0  </td><td>0  </td>
            <td> 0  </td><td>0  </td><td>0 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="alt">
            <td nowrap>" "Date)"</td><td> 3 </td><td> 12.1</td><td> 3  </td><td>38.88</td>
            <td>  <a>4</a> </td><td>  14.52 </td>
            <td class = "standout meter"><span style="width: 55%;"></span> <div style="position:relative; z-index:5;">55</div>  </td>  <td>4:20p</td>
            <td>77  </td><td>200  </td><td> <a>277 </a> </td><td> 30  </td><td>60  </td><td class = "standout "> 90 </td>
            <td> 0  </td><td>0 </td><td> 0  </td><td>0  </td><td>0  </td><td>0  </td>
            <td> 0  </td><td>0  </td><td>0 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style = "background-color:#D3ECF2;">
            <td nowrap>" "Date)"</td><td> 3 </td><td> 12.1</td><td> 3  </td><td>38.88</td>
            <td>  <a>4</a> </td><td>  14.52 </td>
            <td class = "standout meter"><span style="width: 80%;"></span> 12  </td>  <td>4:20p</td>
            <td>77  </td><td>200  </td><td> <a>277 </a> </td><td> 30  </td><td>60  </td><td class = "standout "> 90 </td>
            <td> 0  </td><td>0 </td><td> 0  </td><td>0  </td><td>0  </td><td>0  </td>
            <td> 0  </td><td>0  </td><td>0 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="alt">
            <td nowrap>" "Date)"</td><td> 3 </td><td> 12.1</td><td> 3  </td><td>38.88</td>
            <td>  <a>4</a> </td><td>  14.52 </td>
            <td class = "standout meter"><span style="width: 73%;"></span>73  </td>  <td>4:20p</td>
            <td>77  </td><td>200  </td><td> <a>277 </a> </td><td> 30  </td><td>60  </td><td class = "standout "> 90 </td>
            <td> 0  </td><td>0 </td><td> 0  </td><td>0  </td><td>0  </td><td>0  </td>
            <td> 0  </td><td>0  </td><td>0 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style = "background-color:#D3ECF2;">
            <td>Averages: </td><td> callin  </td><td>durin  </td><td>callout  </td>
            <td>durout  </td><td>totcals  </td><td>totdur  </td><td>
            calls_min  </td><td> N/A </td><td> N/A </td><td>extemre  </td><td>intemre  </td>
            <td>totemre  </td><td>extemse  </td><td>intemse  </td><td>totemse  </td>
            <td>
            cdcal  </td><td>cdvm  </td><td>cscal  </td><td>custCal  </td>
            <td>cusmod  </td><td>quocre  </td><td>quomod  </td><td>0  </td>
            <td>0  </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Totals: </td><td> callin  </td><td>durin  </td>
            <td>callout  </td><td>durout  </td><td>totcals  </td><td>totdur  </td>
            <td>    calls_min  </td><td> N/A </td><td> N/A </td><td>extemre  </td><td>intemre  </td><td>totemre  </td>
            <td>extemse  </td><td>intemse  </td><td>totemse  </td><td>cdcal  </td>
            <td>cdvm  </td><td>cscal  </td><td>custCal  </td><td>cusmod  </td>
            <td>quocre  </td><td>quomod  </td><td> 0  </td><td> 0  </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think there is going to be an easy css solution. I would suggest creating a PHP script that generates an image of the loading bar and then use that instead. Or you could use something like PhantomJS to create a screenshot of the table and send that instead of the HTML/CSS.

Comment: @pamblam, thanks for the comment. We dynamically generate this from service in our company... I guess I will just pass this meter option then...

Comment: For somebody to write up, you could do a background gradient, perhaps, or background image.